# scikit-learn installation error

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

i'm trying to install the scikit-learn-0.14.1 in my osx 10.6.8  but as i've been told, i have to install numpy and scipy before. However i'm getting the following error msg when i try to run each one installation setup.py program. what should i do?

NumPY-1.8.1
       File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 682, in get_mathlib_info
raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

SciPY-0.14.0
     ValueError: numpy >= 1.4 is required (detected 1.2.1 from   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/**init**.pyc)

Scikit-learn-0.14.1

```
  error: Command "g++-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -c sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o" failed with exit status 127
```

Comment: You don't have working C and C++ compilers installed.

Comment: thanks now its running. Now i getting an error msg when i try to install the scipy. ValueError: numpy >= 1.4 is required (detected 1.2.1 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc)

but i have installed the numpy 1.8. do you know why it's not finding the 1.8 version ?

Answer (score 0):

Easier to downloand the Anaconda distribution. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Comment: just leaving a link is discouraged.